# Sales Tax on Trades

Tags: united-states, california, sales-tax

I traded my laptop for my neighbor's TV.
We live in Los Angeles, California.
Do we owe any sales tax to any government?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer? No.

Now, let's see why. Start here at the [California  Department of Tax and Fee Administration](https://www.cdtfa.ca.gov/taxes-and-fees/applying-tax-sales-purchases-faq.htm).

Your transaction is a *barter*: the action or system of exchanging goods or services without using money.  According to my linked page,

> The use of barter or exchanges is considered the same as making sales or purchases under the Sales and Use Tax Laws. The fair market value of the property or services received is normally the amount to which tax will apply.

That sounds like you should each pay tax, but this is not correct because the same page answers the question  of **what is taxable**:

> Retail sales of tangible personal property in California are generally subject to sales tax.

You and your neighbor are not engaging in a retail sale. It's a private exchange. No tax is due.

If either or both of you were in the business of selling your item (let's say you own a store that sells computers) then you **would** be responsible for paying sales tax by the barter rule, which prevents businesses from engaging in mutual trade without tax consequence.

Comment: if you want to be super compliant, there is still capital gains or loss to consider at the federal and state level but that's outside the scope of the question.

Comment: But, don't non-retail purchases of used items (e.g., on eBay or Craigslist) require paying sales tax?  It seems your second quote above says no, but I have been told yes...could you make your answer more thorough by clarifying this case too (keep assuming all parties are in California)?

Comment: I am not sure that "retail sales" do not include "private exchange". But even considering them different and unrelated concepts, #2 only says that retail sales are subject to sales tax. It does not say private exchanges are not subject to sales tax.